# how long will a 12V 5W solar panel take to charge a 12V 1.3Ah `lead acid battery

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, panel

i wanted to know how long will it take for the 12V 5W solar panel to charge a 12V 1.3Ah battery. and also whats the maximum voltage that the panel can produce

Answer (score 1):

12VDC is the nominal output voltage but may run as high as 17VDC<sup>1</sup>.  If you actually achieve 5W output from the panel that would be 0.41A at 12VDC.  Thus the theoretical minimal time to charge is 1.3Ah/0.41A = 3.17h.  In the real world though you'll see losses from the charge circuitry, atmospheric attenuation, sub-optimal orientation, etc.  Realistically, under good conditions you'd probably be looking at a full day or more to charge the battery.

<sup>1</sup> https://www.solaronline.com.au/solar_system_basics.html

Comment: A 12V panel is designed to charge a 12V lead-acid battery. A 12V lead-acid battery is actually a 13.8V battery that charges at ~14V, and a 12V array will have some overhead to allow for the cables and charge controller. A 5W 12V array will be around 0.33A at 15V. and not much more at short circuit. 4 hours. Still a full day.

Comment: @david Yea, I was intentionally vague because I knew my numbers were a bit off.  It's been a very long time since I've worked with PV circuits.